# Disable Selection For WatchKit TableRow

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

Perhaps I'm overlooking the proper usage in Apple's documentation, but I am trying to figure out how to programmatically disable only certain rows in a WatchKit table.

I see in Interface Builder that there is an ability to make an entire TabRowController selectable or not (based on the NSObject `isSelectable` protocol), but I seem to be having trouble discerning how to disable the ability to tap only certain rows.

**InterfaceController.swift**

```
...
for (index, file) in files.enumerate() {
        if let row = fileTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? FileTableRowController {

            row.fileLabel.setText(file.fileName)


            if file.fileType == "file" {
            row.something.isSelectable = false
            }

        }
...
```

Has anyone had success accomplishing the ability to disable the  `isSelectable` state of a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, WatchKit doesn't support it at this time. all you can do is enable/disable an entire table row in storyboard. About the best you can do is use

`func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int)`

to determine what if any action to take when a row is selected.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you!